# How to use same button on different SQL table in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have "Delete" button and have 2 different tables. How to use same button to change info in different tables.

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM radars WHERE id = ?');

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['delete']);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

It works, but i need this button  have to work on this table also

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM drivers WHERE driverId = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['delete']);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

My button looks like this

```
<button  name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >Delete</button>
```

Or

```
<button  name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['driverId']; ?>" >Delete </button>
```

Comment: Is it really just one button, or a button on each row of the table?

Comment: as  you assign different values to the value alttributed  you could assing different name and check the correct index entry in $_GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button name to indicate which table to delete from.

```
<button  name="delete_radar" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >Delete</button>
```

Or

```
<button  name="delete_driver" value="<?php echo $row['driverId']; ?>" >Delete </button>
```

Then the PHP code can be like:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete_radar'])) {
    // code to delete from radar table
} elseif (isset($_GET['delete_driver'])) {
    // code to delete from drivers table
}
```

A more general way is to add a hidden input to the form.

```
<form>
<input name="table" type="hidden" value="radar">
<button name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
</form>

<form>
<input name="table" type="hidden" value="drivers">
<button name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['driverId']; ?>">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Then the code can be like:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $table_key_cols = array('radar' => 'id', 'drivers' => 'driverId');

    $table = $_GET['table'];
    if (isset($table_key_cols[$table])) {
        $col = $table_key_cols[$table];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $col = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['delete']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think about it, but start imagine you have not 2 table but 100. There have to be easier way

Comment: I just edited my response which will work on any table with any ID field.

Comment: @Darius I've added a more general solution.

Comment: Maybe your answer also correct, but i don`t know how yours if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $table = $_GET['table'];
    // code to delete from the specified table
} works

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can construct the query dynamically from `$_GET['table']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that info as well, something like:

```
<button  name="delete" value="radars|id|<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >Delete</button> 
<button  name="delete" value="drivers|driverId|<?php echo $row['driverId']; ?>" >Delete</button>
```

and then in your php:

```
$chunks = explode('|', $_GET['delete']);
```

which will give you table in `$chunks[0]`, `$chunks[1]` field name and id in `$chunks[2]`

And your Query will look something like this:

```
'DELETE FROM $chunks[0] WHERE $chunks[1] = $chunks[2]';
```

Comment: Your answer would be best solution in this problem, but it doesnt work.  if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $chunks = explode('|', $_GET['delete']);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM' . $chunks[0]. ' WHERE ' .$chunks[1].' = ?');
    
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $chunks[2]);
    
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}

Comment: You are missing an "s". It is not $chunk[0], variable name is $chunks, so it would be $chunks[0].

Comment: it look like sql don`t like explode function. Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Comment: Explode function has nothing to do with sql. $chunks[0] is just another variable. Echo $chunks[2] and see if you are receiving any data.